# SonataMedia - generated public url for video returns wrong filename and type

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I use SonataMediaBundle 2.3.3 with Symfony 2.5.12. When I generate a publicUrl, it gives me a wrong path (moreover with png extension).

Here is my sonata.yml file:

```
sonata_media: 
    contexts:
        default:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image

            formats:
                ..

        avatar:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image

            formats:
                ..

        avatar-video:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.file

            formats:
                mobile: { width: 1850 , quality: 768}

    cdn:
        ..

    providers:
        image:
            ..
        file:
            filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.s3
            allowed_mime_types: ['video/quicktime']
```

Within my controller:

```
avatar = $request->request->get('avatar');
$path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'avatar');
$fileSize = file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($avatar));
$providerName = 'sonata.media.provider.file';
$context = 'avatar-video';

$mediaManager = $this->get('sonata.media.manager.media');

$media = $mediaManager->create();
$media->setBinaryContent(new File($path));
$mediaManager->save($media, $context, $providerName);
$user->setImage($media);

$provider = $this->get($media->getProviderName());

$format = $provider->getFormatName($media, "mobile");
$publicUrl =  $provider->generatePublicUrl($media, $format);
```

returns a wrong filename with wrong 'png' extension:

```
http://../avatar-video_mobile/file.png
```

However, I can retrieve a correctly created file name based on provider reference (ex.: db826fcb917f488cadf3b6bf19594bc0e2b123ac.qt):

```
$currentProviderRef = $user->getImage()->getProviderReference();
```

But still, I need to hardcode the whole path to this ressource. Is there any way to get a correct publicUrl for the custom video file? For instance the link to this 'qt' quicktime file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The provider class is Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\ImageProvider.
There you will find the method:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function generatePublicUrl(MediaInterface $media, $format)
{
    if ($format == 'reference') {
        $path = $this->getReferenceImage($media);
    } else {
        $path = $this->thumbnail->generatePublicUrl($this, $media, $format);
    }

    return $this->getCdn()->getPath($path, $media->getCdnIsFlushable());
}
```

So in your case, just use the same function, but use "reference" as format, this will return the path of your file.

$provider->generatePublicUrl($media,'reference');